# How to set the scheme for Authorize attribute from a .txt file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

My controller is protected with Authorize attribute. What I want to do is to tell the Authorize attribute to use Windows schema or no schema at all. How would I accomplish that?

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes)]
```

1. Case: AuthSchemes = "Windows"
2. Case: AuthSchemes = ""

I want to change the schema during run-time, so the administrator will be able to change authentication settings basically.

Answer (score 0):

After long time of figuring out I have managed to get this working, but in a not so elegant way.

I decided not to use the Authorize attribute, instead I've decided to make a custom authentication process. So basically I migrated authentication middleware to ASP.NET CORE 2.0 with custom authentication process, following this resource [Migrating authentication middleware to ASP.NET CORE 2.0.](http://geeklearning.io/how-to-migrate-your-authentication-middleware-to-asp-net-core-2-0/)

With this set up, I have made a simple class, which will be used when reading from .json file:

```
public class AuthenticationSettings
{
    public string AuthenticatonScheme { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

I have also made a .json file which contains information of weather our application should use Windows authentication or not. Reading of the file happens in Startup class in ConfigureServices() method. If windows is set to true we create custom policy (with our scheme which is now set) which is then applied globally:

```
services.AddAuthorization(o =>  // we create policy with our custom sheme
{
    o.AddPolicy("WinPolicy", b =>
    {
       b.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
       b.AuthenticationSchemes = new List<string> { auth_settings.AuthenticatonScheme }; // here we set the windows scheme
    });
});
services.AddMvc(o =>
{
       o.Conventions.Add(new AddAuthorizeFiltersControllerConvention()); // we apply the policy
});
```